# Method not found exception when generating views with entity framework power tools

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm working in a solution with a few projects in it. One handles our db context. Using Entity Framework 6 and Power Tools Beta 4, I right click the dbContext.cs file and select "Generate Views." I receive the following error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmModel System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbModel.get_StoreModel()'.
   at CodeFirstStoreFunctions.FunctionsConvention.Apply(EntityContainer item, DbModel model)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConventionsConfiguration.ModelConventionDispatcher.Dispatch[T](T item)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConventionsConfiguration.ModelConventionDispatcher.VisitEdmEntityContainer(EntityContainer item)
   at System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmModelVisitor.VisitCollection[T](IEnumerable`1 collection, Action`1 visitMethod)
   at System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmModelVisitor.VisitEntityContainers(IEnumerable`1 entityContainers)
   at System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmModelVisitor.VisitEdmModel(EdmModel item)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConventionsConfiguration.ModelConventionDispatcher.VisitEdmModel(EdmModel item)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConventionsConfiguration.ModelConventionDispatcher.Dispatch()
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConventionsConfiguration.ApplyStoreModel(DbModel model)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_CodeFirstModel()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.DbContextPackage.Handlers.ViewContextHandler.ViewContext(MenuCommand menuCommand, Object context, Type systemContextType)
```

Any ideas what could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me recently with the same version of EF Power Tools but the problem disappeared once I did a system restart and a clean build for the solution in Visual Studio.

I saw in other forums that this exception raises in other extensions, tools and libraries, usually caused by an old version of a library that is still hanging around, so I guess that clean build did the fix by removing the old compilation of the library where I have my DbContext derived class and generating the new one.